# Failure and succeed probability for dependent two trials

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains

I am Ph.D. student and I am now needed some help, please.
Let $P_1$ the probability of succeed in the first attempt. If we succeed in the first attempt we don't go to a second attempt.

If we fail so this happens with probability $Q_1$, then we go to another attempt but the problem now the second attempt depends on the first attempt, I will explain.

Suppose that we have a threshold $T$. when we send in the first attempt we receive amount equal $A$. Now if $A \ge T$ this mean succeed in the first attempt with probability $P_1$, we can say 
$$P_1=P(A \ge T)$$
Now if we have $A<T$ this is a failure and this is $Q_1$ failure probability from the first attempt with

$$Q_1=P(A<T)$$

Now if we fail in the first attempt we go to a second attempt and we re-send again and we receive another amount $B$ but now we combine with the first amount $A$.
The probability of success in second attempt $P_2$ given by
$$P_2=P(A+B \ge T |A<T)$$ So if we have only $P_1$ is given how we compute $P_2$ and $Q_2$ and assume that $Q_1=1-P_1$.

Thanks in advance and I am sorry for my English

Comment: This is confusing, to me at least.  You should  state up-front what the ranDom elements are.  Is $A$ a random variable?  Is $T$ a random variable? What are their distributions?  Are they dependent on the outcome of the first attempt?

Comment: Non just numbers $A$ and $T$ i have for example $P_1\in\{0,0.1,\cdots,0.9,1\}$, and $T=constant$ and $A=constant$ also $B=constatnt$. just to explan that in first attempt i recieve amount if exced $T$ ok but if now i re-send and reciev another amount if $A+B\ge T$ given that $A< T$ so i succed in second attempt else i fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly...

Assuming that $Q_1 > 0$ and that $A,B$ are random variables with distribution functions $F_1,F_2$, respectively, then we can write
$$
P_2 = P(A+B \ge T | A < T) = \frac{P(A+B \ge T,\ A  <T)}{P(A < T)} = \frac{1}{Q_1}\int_0^T \int_{T-a}^{\infty}dF_2(b)dF_1(a)
$$
and $Q_2 = 1-P_2$.

Comment: ak thank you so much i think it will be helpful thanks a gain